# Get only given keys from a JSON object dynamically

Tags: python, sql, json, postgresql

I have a Python function called `sandbox_configurations`:

```py
def get_sandbox_csv_query(self):
    q = """
    SELECT string_agg(col, ',') as cols
    FROM (
        SELECT json_field_name || ' AS ' || csv_field_name as col
        FROM sandbox_configurations
        WHERE include is true
        ORDER BY sequence_id, sandbox_column_config_id
    ) a
    """
    return self.engine.execute(q).fetchall()
```

This basically gives me something like this:

```
name AS name,name AS name,full_name AS full_name,skus AS skus,created_dtmz AS created_dtmz
```

I have another query that looks like:

```sql
SELECT COALESCE(json_agg(a.*), '[]'::json) FROM (
    SELECT sku.*
         , CASE WHEN data->>'mechanism_cd' = 'override_zone_price' THEN 'dollar_amount' ELSE data->>'mechanism_cd' END as mechanism_cd
         , p.product_name, p.product_cd
         , sl2.*
         , zone_id = 4 as is_main_zone
         , zone_id = 7 as is_last_zone
    FROM pricing.simulation_skus sku
    LEFT JOIN dimensions_new.product p on p.product_id = sku.product_id
    LEFT JOIN dimensions_new.store_level_2 sl2 on sl2.store_level_2_id = sku.zone_id
    LEFT JOIN dimensions_new.product_attributes pa ON pa.product_id = sku.product_id
    WHERE simulation_id=252
    ORDER BY product_id, zone_id) a;
```

This gives me an aggregated JSON results that looks like this (aka "products"):

```json
[
  {
    "id": 2582471,
    "simulation_id": 252,
    "product_id": 13868,
    "product_name": "COWL SEAL 1 EA MTROM",
    "product_cd": "10079111",
  }
]
```

For the purpose of this example I am only showing an array with 1 item, but there can be multiple.

From this, I only want to get the columns returned from `get_sandbox_csv_query` as shown above.

I tried changing:

```sql
SELECT COALESCE(json_agg(a.name, a.full_name, a.skus, a.created_dtmz), '[]'::json) ...
```

However, some of the rows don't actually have `full_name`, so it returns errors like:

> ```
> [42703] ERROR: column a.first_name does not exist Position: 26
> ```

Am I doing this completely wrong? Do I even need `json_agg()`? My goal is to get all the data for specified columns.

To give a bigger picture: I am joining multiple tables, then generating output for `products`, and from that output I want to only display items specified as specified by `get_sandbox_csv_query()`.

Answer (score 0):

You might use your query basically as is, and then extract desired keys using this custom Postgres function:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_json_select_keys(_js json, _keys text[])
  RETURNS json
  LANGUAGE sql STABLE STRICT PARALLEL SAFE AS
$func$
SELECT json_object_agg (t.key, t.value ORDER BY ord)
FROM   unnest(_keys) WITH ORDINALITY k(key, ord)
JOIN   json_each(_js) t USING (key);
$func$;
```

I chose the `json` variant preserving order of keys and duplicates, since that seems to be your setup. You might chose a better variant from here (with detailed explanation):

- **[How to select sub-object with given keys from JSONB?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/290029/3684)**

The function expects an **array of key names**, so let's modify your "sandbox" a bit:

```py
def get_sandbox_csv_query(self):
        q = """
        SELECT ARRAY (
            SELECT json_field_name
            FROM   sandbox_configurations
            WHERE  include
            ORDER  BY sequence_id, sandbox_column_config_id
            ) 
        """
        return self.engine.execute(q).fetchall()
```

Then:

```sql
SELECT COALESCE(
         json_agg(
            f_json_select_keys(
               to_json(a.*)
             , ARRAY (SELECT json_field_name  -- your "get_sandbox_csv_query()" inlined
                      FROM   sandbox_configurations
                      WHERE  include
                      ORDER  BY sequence_id, sandbox_column_config_id) 
            )
         )
       , '[]'::json
       )
FROM  (
      -- your subquery
      ) a;
```